# Set a transient object variable without serializing in Camunda

Tags: java, serialization, camunda, transient

I have a process in Camunda that doesn't have any user tasks. Iy has only some service tasks.
I want to set a transient Object variable and then get in several tasks and manipulate it but Camunda forces me to make it implement the `Serializable` interface.

My code is:

```
TypedValue transient_ctx = Variables.objectValue( new BpmContext(), true).create();

ProcessInstanceWithVariables process_res = 
       runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey(param.getProcessKey())
                    .setVariable("Param", transient_ctx)
                    .executeWithVariablesInReturn();
```

but get the following exception:

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Cannot find serializer for value 'ObjectValue [value=org.BpmContext@433a4e29, isDeserialized=true, serializationDataFormat=null, objectTypeName=null, serializedValue=null, isTransient=true]'.
```

Is there any way for setting a transient object normally without serializing that?

Comment: Sure dear, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to transport the data as process data, then Camunda requires its serialization, be it in Java or other serialization data formats.

Since you are ok with a transient process data it means you do not expect the data to be available for longer than the life of the current thread.
I guess a ThreadLocal variable would also do the trick for you. There are many examples on the internet. This is one: https://codedelay.com/threadlocal-variable-in-java-with-example/